# How to count down both cooldown and duration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, repeat, ienumerator

In a small simulation game (A.I. spaceship shooter) that I am developing, I am trying to come up with an effective shield function or IEnumerator which can be called or started and do multiple things:

- Count down the shield's cooldown if it is above zero
- Activate the shield for the set duration (5 seconds) if the cooldown has ended
- Deactivate the shield when the duration expires

However, I run into some problems when trying this using only an Ienumerator. I have been able to use IEnumerators to count down timers and cooldowns before but trying to do both a cooldown and duration doesn't seem to work as Unity does not let me WaitForSeconds twice without leaving the IEnumerator.

Similarly, each ship has a turret and inside of that turret is an IEnumerator which fires or counts down its cooldown, whichever is needed for the situation.

```
// Fire continuously if in range and we have more than 1 shot left
    // Otherwise, reload for (rate) seconds and reset shots left
    public IEnumerator Fire(Vector2 target) {
        firing = true;

        if (cooldown <= 0) {
            if (bullets > 0) {
                // Fire a bullet
                bullets--;

                // Instatiate the bullet
                }
            } else {
                // Reload
                cooldown = rate;
                bullets = count;
            }
        } else {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            cooldown--;
        }

        firing = false;
        yield break;
    }
```

The Fire Coroutine is called by using the `firing` flag to check whether it is running or not and if it is not call

```
var fire = turret.Fire(shootTarget + offset);
if (!turret.firing && InRange() == true) {
    StartCoroutine(fire);
}
```

every second or so if the ship is alive and we have a target.

I do think that my current use of the IEnumerator is not recommended because it has to be called at least every second, but with how small the environment is at the moment, it doesn't appear to be an issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Fire bullets State not wait time , so you will fire all bullet in one frame

Comment: Where/How do you call your Coroutines? Also please add the `IEnumerator` for the Shields...

Comment: @derHugo I've added some extra code to the question to see if that will help.

Comment: My question is: Is this called only once e.g. in `OnTriggerEnter` or is it called every frame like e.g. in `Update`?

Comment: @derHugo It is called in an InvokeRepeating which calls a function ```Shoot()``` which determines if the ship is alive, in range of the target, and isn't currently shooting. The function repeats about every second.

Answer (score 0):

Quick code without coroutines, no idea if it works in game. Should give you some idea though, I hope.

```
public class Shield : MonoBehaviour {

public float duration;
public float cooldown;
public float lastActivated;
public bool IsActivated => (lastActivated - (Time.time - duration)) > 0;
public bool onCoolDown => (lastActivated - (Time.time - cooldown)) > 0;

public void Activate(){
if(onCoolDown) return;

lastActivated = Time.time;
}

void LateUpdate(){
if(IsActivated) //Show shield effects, blahblah
else //Do nothing, blahblah
}

}
```